# Python super().__init__() with multiple inheritances

Tags: python-3.x, class, multiple-inheritance

```
class School:
    def __init__(self, school_name):
        self._school = school_name

class Exam:
    def __init__(self, exam_name):
        self._exam_name = exam_name
    def credit(self):
        return 3

class Test(School, Exam):
    def __init__(self, school_name, exam_name):
        self._date = "Oct 7"
        super().__init__(school_name, exam_name)

test = Test('Success', 'Math')
print(test._school) 
print(test._exam_name)
```

I just want to know why super().**init**() can't work here. And if I insist to use super(), what's the correct way to do so that I can pass in the school_name and exam_name successfully.

Comment: The biggest issue is the semantics are wrong and that is causing the code to be confusing. A Test is not a kind of School. This is a case where composition makes more sense.

Comment: `super().__init__(school_name, exam_name)` doesn't work because neither of the inherited implementations take two (three, with `self`) parameters. Also neither of them calls `super` themselves, so only one will get invoked anyway.

Comment: If you have an instance method (generally true for `__init__`) you need to get the class, and an easy way to do that is just `type(self)`, then you can access the `__mro__` attribute which is a tuple of classes that your class inherits from. calling `__init__` on `Exam` from `Test.__init__` could then look like: `type(self).__mro__[1].__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super function only calls the parent class from MRO order. Acc to this, your prefered class would be School and the init of School will be called. You have to give only school_name as parameter while calling `super().__init__(self,school_name)`. But if you want to call particular `__init__()`, then it is better to use `<parent_class>.<method>(<parameters>)`. If you want to call both the init functions, try doing this:

```
class School:
    def __init__(self, school_name):
        self._school = school_name

class Exam:
    def __init__(self, exam_name):
        self._exam_name = exam_name
    def credit(self):
        return 3

class Test(School, Exam):
    def __init__(self, school_name, exam_name):
        self._date = "Oct 7"
        School.__init__(self,school_name)
        Exam.__init__(self,exam_name)

test = Test('Success', 'Math')
print(test._school) 
print(test._exam_name)
```

Try doing this

Answer (score 0):

if you want to inherit 2 classes, you can also do it this way

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, param1='hello from B'):
        print('start B __init__')`enter code here`
        self.param1=param1
class C:
    def __init__(self, param2='hello from C'):
        print('start C __init__')
        super().__init__()
        print('end C __init__')
        self.param2 = param2

class D(C,B):
    def __init__(self, param='hello from D'):
        super().__init__()
        print('start D __init__')
        print(self.param1,self.param2)
d = D()
```

The super().**init** in the C_class calls the constructor of B_Class

any number of functions can be inserted as long as the inherited class calls the next one

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, param1='hello from B'):
        print('start B __init__')
        self.param1=param1
        
class C:
    def __init__(self, param2='hello from C'):
        print('start C __init__')
        super().__init__()
        print('end C __init__')
        self.param2 = param2
        
class E:
    def __init__(self, param3='hello from E'):
        print('start E __init__')
        super().__init__()
        print('end E __init__')
        self.param3=param3

class D(C,E,B):
    def __init__(self, param='hello from D'):
        super().__init__()
        print('start D __init__')
        print(self.param1,self.param2)
d = D()
```

And if you don't want to pay attention to which class comes first, you can provide all classes with super()._*init*()

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, param1='hello'):
        print('start B __init__')
        super().__init__()
        self.param1=param1
```

then can you

```
class D(E,C,B):
    def __init__(self, param='hello from D'):
        super().__init__()
class D(B,C,E):
    def __init__(self, param='hello from D'):
        super().__init__()
class D(C,B,E):
    def __init__(self, param='hello from D'):
        super().__init__()
```